# Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM: Could not find artifact

Tags: magnolia

Hi I have an sample project in Magnolia Blossom. When i run the project it is showing Error.

This is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
    <groupId>info.magnolia</groupId>
    <artifactId>magnolia-parent-pom-community-module</artifactId>
    <version>17</version>
</parent>

<groupId>com.hyro</groupId>
<artifactId>hyro-magnolia-blossom</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>Hyro Magnolia Blossom</name>
<description>Hyro Magnolia and Blossom working example</description>

<properties>
    <magnolia.version>4.3.6</magnolia.version>
    <blossom.version>1.1.1</blossom.version>
    <spring.version>3.0.4.RELEASE</spring.version>
</properties>

<build>
    <resources>
        <!-- Add the Attributes from the POM to properties files -->
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <!-- Compiler version -->
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!-- Add timestamp to configuration files -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-beta-3</version>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>create</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <format>{0,date,yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'+10:00'}</format>
                <items>
                    <item>timestamp</item>
                </items>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Magnolia Dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.magnolia</groupId>
        <artifactId>magnolia-core</artifactId>
        <version>${magnolia.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.magnolia</groupId>
        <artifactId>magnolia-module-mail</artifactId>
        <version>${magnolia.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.magnolia</groupId>
        <artifactId>magnolia-gui</artifactId>
        <version>${magnolia.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.magnolia</groupId>
        <artifactId>magnolia-module-admininterface</artifactId>
        <version>${magnolia.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.magnolia</groupId>
        <artifactId>magnolia-module-templating</artifactId>
        <version>${magnolia.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.magnolia</groupId>
        <artifactId>magnolia-module-fckeditor</artifactId>
        <version>${magnolia.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Blossom Module -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.magnolia</groupId>
        <artifactId>magnolia-module-blossom</artifactId>
        <version>${blossom.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring MVC -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

at the  it is showing the following error:

> Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM: Could not find artifact info.magnolia:magnolia-parent-pom-community-module:pom:1.0.12-SNAPSHOT and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM

some where i got an idea of deleting all the *lastupdated.xml file but it is not helping.
Anything wrong with the Pom.xml ?

can anyone suggest me how to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

I tried building your pom. It was missing `</project>` at the end. I assume this was just copy paste error. Anyway it built fine for me using maven 3.2.1. I did verify info.magnolia:magnolia-parent-pom-community-module:pom:1.0.12-SNAPSHOT does not exist in the nexus.

I did a mvn dependency:tree on your pom and I don't see any dependency on the pom referenced in your error. Maybe you should try and analyze the pom and your end and see where this dependency is being brought in.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [Magnolia Nexus](https://nexus.magnolia-cms.com/#nexus-search;gav~info.magnolia~magnolia-parent-pom-community-module~~~) the latest version of parent pom is 29. Your one is quite old. I suggest you change your pom to

```
<parent>
  <groupId>info.magnolia</groupId>
  <artifactId>magnolia-parent-pom-community-module</artifactId>
  <version>29</version>
</parent>
```

HTH,
Jan